Importing module within the celery task
I wonder whether there could be difference between the following code snippets
from some_module.sub_module import some_function
@app.task(soft_time_limit=16, time_limit=18)
def call_function():
    some_function()

and
@app.task(soft_time_limit=16, time_limit=18)
def call_function():
    from some_module.sub_module import some_function
    some_function()

I'm using celery with Django and there are around 16 celery processes.
Is there some difference between th abovementioned pieces of the code?
I feel like there can be some difference.
What if inside some_module.sub_module module there is a variable? Will all workers share it? Or absolutely everything is separated?
Thank you.

This question is similar to: In Python, what happens when you import inside of a function?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
